# Synchronize parse background query withandoid acitvity

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am developing an android application using parse BaaS. Parse execute all cloud queries asynchronously, but i want to execute it synchronously. Problem is that in activity's onCreate method i want to refresh 7 parse objects before activity to process further. But with current asynchronous calls my activity execute next code with old data in parse objects because objects are updated in background and the time they are updated android has already executed next chunk of code. Is there anyway to synchronize this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Parse cloud functions either synchronously or asynchronously.

To call cloud functions synchronously use:

```
ParseCloud.callFunction(String, Map)
```

If you are calling synchronously though, be aware this will block the thread and will adversely affect the user experience.

Preferred way is to call your cloud functions asynchronously and update your objects on callback:

```
callFunctionInBackground(String name, Map<String,?> params, FunctionCallback<T> callback)
```

Comment: Actually i don't want UI to stuck during aync call but i want a progress dialog. Right now I start progress dialog before calling all async functions and finishes it in callback but problem is that  i don't know which call with finish first so sometimes dialog finishes before all aync task execute completely. Is there anyway to ensure that dialog finishes after all 7 calls are completed?

Comment: I am an iOS developer so will try to provide some logic and you can figure out how to implement in Android. You could you a flag set to false at the start of each query and change it to true on callback. Then you stop your progress dialog only when all of the flag's are set to true.